# How can I make an int[] parameter required in web api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I have a bunch of operations on my api that are generic GetById and GetByIds that pull an entity out and return it via a formatter.

These operations look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ByIds")]
public IHttpActionResult ByIds([FromUri]int[] ids)
{
    var items = _myContext.SomeEntity.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.ID)).ToList();
    return SomeFormatter(items);
}
```

If you hit this with `http://localhost/api/SomeEntity/ByIds?ids=1&ids=2` for example, you get an array with 1 and 2 in as you'd expect.

If you hit this with `http://localhost/api/SomeEntity/ByIds?ids=` you might expect to get an empty array, but you get `int[1]` with a value of `0` in it.

I suspect what happens is it recognises it as one element specified, cannot convert it, so uses `default(int)` and puts that into the array, which gives you an int array with one value, the value of 0.

However if you hit it with `http://localhost/api/SomeEntity/ByIds?ids=potato` then you get an invalid modelstate and I automatically handle that.

The question is, what's a catch all approach of mapping an empty query parameter value to either an empty array or a ModelState error (i.e. the same behaviour as potato if you supply an empty value)? I think a modelstate error would be preferred and is more logical.

Comment: I hit this problem too. Did you find a solution? In my case I'd prefer an empty array to the ModelState error.

Answer (score 1):

The int value of 0 occurs because 0 is the same as null for a string. If you want your int to have a value of null use int?

Basicly:

```
int i = 0
```

Is the integer equivalent of

```
string myString = null;
```

And if you want your int to be null use:

```
int? i = null;
```

So what happens is the array wants at least one item, it will not assign a value to that one item. But since the default value of an integer is 0, it will get that value

Comment: And in action, check if count == 1 and item 0 is null, add error to modelstate.